# Gradle: Ant task for Hibernate InstrumentTask cannot be found

Tags: hibernate, ant, gradle

I've gradle build file:

```
task hibernateInstrumentation {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'hibernateInstrumentation' ,
            classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
            classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask'){

    }
    ant.hibernateInstrumentation(verbose: 'true') {
        fileset(
            dir: "${project.buildDir}",
            inculde: 'mypackage/model/*.class'
        )
    }
}

compileJava.doLast {
    hibernateInstrumentation
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion",
  compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA',
  // ...
}
```

But when I start gradle

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':application'.

> taskdef class org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask cannot be found
>   using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
>   
>   So look like for some reason 'AntClassLoader' don't use provided dependencies as class path (see `project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath`)

Answer (score 1):

The code from the question has typos and incorrect nesting of elements. This works for me:

```
task hibernateInstrumentation << {
    ant.taskdef(name: 'hibernateInstrumentation',
            classpath: project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath,
            classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask')

    ant.hibernateInstrumentation(verbose: 'true') {
        fileset(dir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/main") {
            include(name: 'mypackage/model/*.class')
        }
    }
}

compileJava.doLast {
    hibernateInstrumentation.execute()
}

dependencies {
    def hibernateVersion = '5.0.3.Final'

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA'
    // ...
}
```

The environment used:

```
Gradle:   2.9
Groovy:   2.4.4
Ant:      Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:      1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation 25.60-b23)
```

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works. Just check your paths:

fileset(dir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/java/main") for Gradle 4.5

Answer (score 0):

You are calling ant.taskdef in the configuration phase before the classpath has been set up properly. You want to move it to the execution phase. Something like:

```
    task hibernateInstrumentation << {
       ant.taskdef ...
    }
```